# When to use curly brackets vs curved brackets in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently taking an online course to learn React and I'm confused as to when I should be using `{` vs `(`.

I have 3 files:

### App.js

```js
const App = () => {
```

### card-list.component.jsx

```js
const CardList = ({ monsters }) => (
```

### card.component.jsx

```js
const Card = ({ monster }) => {
```

This is the code that currently works. Notice that on the second code the last character used is `(`. I thought of changing it to `{` to make it consistent with the other files but somehow the card list no longer shows up on the page although I didn't get any compile errors.

Can someone explain this to me and tell me when I should use one over the other?

Comment: That's a feature of javascript arrow functions, not react specifically. Default syntax is curly brackets + return, but if you have just one expression you can leave the curly brackets out and the return is implied. If you use the shorthand but want it on multiple lines, that's where the parentheses come in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Comment: `=> (` is an _implicit_ return. The `return` keyword is automatically implied. `=> {`: the curly bracket defines a _statement_ and requires an _explicit_ return. Both are fine, you just need to be aware of the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This essentially is a feature of arrow functions in js.

```js
const myArrowFunc = ({key1}) => ("Hello there! " + key1);
```

is essentially the same as

```js
const myArrowFunc = ({key1}) => { return "Hello there! " + key1 };
```

when you leave out the curly brackets, the return is implicit.
When you include the curly brackets, you must explicitly use the return statement.

```js
const someObj = { key1: "value1" };
const someReturn = myArrowFunc(someObj);
console.log(someReturn); // logs "Hello there! value1" to the console
```

Answer (score 2):

`()=>{}` is the syntax of [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

When an arrow function only contains one line that return a value, e.g.:

```
() => { 
    return 1; 
}
```

it can be simplified to

`() => 1`

Now what if you want to return an `object` directly? i.e. how to simplify

```
() => {
    return { foo: "bar" }
}
```

Since an `object` also use `{}`, you cannot write `{foo: "bar"}` directly after the arrow as it will be treated as the function body. Wrapping the `object` within `()` solves the problem since a `()` chunk must be an expression. The above example can be simplified to

```
() => ( { foo : "bar" } )
```